# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException when trying to save record

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am new to the world of JPA and hibernate. I have an entity EMPLOYEE for which I am trying to save a simple empty record but I keep on getting the following exception:

```
 org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'employee0_.employee_id' in 'field list'
```

My entity class looks like this:

```
package com.workforcesoftware.groupmanagementservice.data.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "employeeId")
  private String employeeId;
  @Column(name = "displayEmployeeId")
  private String displayEmployeeId;
  @Column(name = "accountId")
  private String accountId;
  @Column(name = "userId")
  private String userId;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String displayName;
  private String birthDate;
  private String phoneNumber;
  private String originalHireDate;
  private String externalMatchId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
  private List<EffectiveDatedEmployee> effectiveDatedEmployees;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
  private List<Job> jobs;


  public Employee(){ }

  public Employee(String employeeId, String displayEmployeeId, String accountId, String userId, String firstName,
                  String lastName, String displayName, String birthDate, String phoneNumber, String originalHireDate,
                  String externalMatchId, List<EffectiveDatedEmployee> effectiveDatedEmployees, List<Job> jobs) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
    this.displayEmployeeId = displayEmployeeId;
    this.accountId = accountId;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.displayName = displayName;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.originalHireDate = originalHireDate;
    this.externalMatchId = externalMatchId;
    this.effectiveDatedEmployees = effectiveDatedEmployees;
    this.jobs = jobs;
  }
}
```

My repository interface looks like:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, String> {
}
```

Finally, my repository calling code looks like this:

```
    Employee employee = new Employee("1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", null, null);
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
```

Comment: Don't you have any getter setter method in entity class ?

Comment: The column name you have mentioned is `employeeId` while it is still reffering it as `employee_id`. You might have changed the column name later. Drop the table and recreate.

Comment: @AvijitBarua I do have them but removed them from here just for the sake of clarity

Comment: @Pradyskumar It seems like hibernate/JPA don't like camel casing as a naming convention. I turned back to using underscores and the error went away

Comment: In database names are in snakecase ?

Comment: @Eklavya yes they are

Comment: Then you have to do like `@Column(name =employee_id")`